# delete files with specific string in the filename

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

How is it possible to delete files containing a string as an embedded string except at the
beginning or end by using wild-cards.

I'm an amateur started Ubuntu less than a month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with a single expansion pattern. You can use `grep` for filtering instead:

```
ls -d '*foo*' | egrep -v '^foo|foo$' | xargs rm
```

So the `ls` lists everything containing `foo`, then `egrep` removes the files with matches at the beginning/end, and finally `xargs` runs a command (`rm` in this case) on each remainder.

[The dangerous thing about this technique](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) is that filenames may contain special characters like line breaks or asterisks, so use at your own risk!

Answer (score 6):

```
rm ?*foo?*
```

removes files containing foo provided that there is at least one character before and after, so "foobar" and "barfoo" will NOT be deleted, whereas "barfoobar" will be.

As a precaution, do

`ls ?*foo?*`

first to make sure that you aren't deleting the wrong stuff. And be very careful not to accidentally include any spaces as **rm ?* foo?*** is almost certainly very bad. To provide some protection, wrap the argument in quotes, thus

```
rm "?*foo?*"
```

Comment: ahh the old foobarfoobarfoo paradox :-)
I'm gonna assume for the moment that the OP would want that deleting too.

Comment: :)))) is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: Good call on the ls first. rm -v ?*(1)?* didn't do anything like I wanted. I forgot about escaping the brackets.